# Non-persistent attributes in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Does anyone know of a way to specify for an Ember `model` an attribute which is not persisted?

Basically, we're loading some metadata related to each model and sending that data to Ember via the `RESTAdapter` within the model. This metadata can be changed in our app, but is done via using an AJAX call. Once the call succeeds, I want to be able to update this value within the model without Ember sticking its nose in this business by changing the model to the `uncommitted` and doing whatever it does with `transactions` behind the scenes.

I also have the problem that this metadata, which is not data from the `model`'s database record, is passed by the `RESTAdapter` back to the server, which doesn't expect these values. I am using a RoR backend, so the server errors out trying to mass-assign protected attributes which aren't meant to be attributes at all. I know I can scrub the data received on the server, but I would prefer the client to be able to distinguish between persistent data and auxiliary data.

So, to the original question: is there any alternative to Ember-Data's `DS.attr('...')` which will specify a non-persistent attribute?

Comment: See [How to prevent Ember Data from saving attribute (ie., Read-only attribute)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32830068/1067145) for how to skip serializing an attribute to the backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/303) get's merged it will be possible to flag properties as `readOnly`. But till then there are some workarounds to this, e.g. overriding your `addAttributes` method in the Adapter and deal with your special properties, here an example how this could look like:

Define your Model by adding the new option `readOnly`:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  myMetaProperty: DS.attr('metaProperty', {readOnly: true})
});
```

and then on the Adapter:

```
App.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   addAttributes: function(data, record) {
     record.eachAttribute(function(name, attribute) {
       if (!attribute.options.readOnly) {
         this._addAttribute(data, record, name, attribute.type);
       }
     }, this);
   }
 });
```

what this does is to loop over the attributes of your model and when it find's an attribute with the `readOnly` flag set it skips the property.

I hope this mechanism works for your use case.

Comment: Beautiful, I should have been able to find that via Google, my bad. I spent so long looking!

It seems that this will still cause the model to become dirtied, so I'll have to work around that still, but this solves the more difficult portion of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. This should go into their source. Although `transient` sounds like a better fit than `readOnly`

Comment: Ember-data verion 1.0 beta killed this. Any alternative solution?

Answer (score 13):

The other answers to this question work with Ember data versions up to 0.13, and no longer work.
For **Ember data 1.0 beta 3** you can do:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeAttribute: function(record, json, key, attribute) {
    if (attribute.options.transient) {
      return;
    }
    return this._super(record, json, key, attribute);
  }
});
```

Now you can use transient attributes:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', {transient: true})
});
```

These attributes won't be sent to the server when saving records.

Comment: Is this still the case? This is a great solution but the answer is fairly old, has the framework absorbed this now?

Comment: that version is the last one i've used, but theoretically it should work, because the team stated that they're freezing API changes after 1.0

Answer (score 6):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32830068/1067145), to prevent a field from being serialized, override the default serializer for your model:

In `app/serializers/person.js`:

```
export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    admin: { serialize: false }
  }
});
```

[See here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2106) for the source PR. This solution works in Ember Data 2, and should work in older versions as well.

Comment: `serialize: false` works perfectly with `DS.RESTSerializer` (ember-data v1.0.0-beta.16.1).

Comment: This is the most "correct", recommended solution. Also see: [How to prevent Ember Data from saving attribute (ie., Read-only attribute)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32830068/1067145).

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

This answer is most likely out of date with the current releases of Ember Data. I wouldn't use anything in my answer.

---

I'm answering this question for reference, and because your comment indicated that the record remains `isDirty`, but here is my solution for **read-only**, **non-persistent**, **non-dirty** attributes.

Overriding the `addAtributes` method in your Serializer prevents `readOnly` attributes from being sent to the server, which is probably exactly what you want, but you need to extend (or `reopen`) your adapter to override the `dirtyRecordsForAttributeChange` to prevent the record from becoming dirty:

```
App.CustomAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  dirtyRecordsForAttributeChange: function(dirtySet, record, attrName, newValue, oldValue) {
    meta = record.constructor.metaForProperty(attrName);
    if (meta && meta.options.readOnly) { return; }
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  };
});
```

Then you can use `readOnly` attributes like so:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string', {readOnly: true})
});

user = App.User.find(1);      # => {id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}
user.set('name', 'Jane Doe'); #
user.get('isDirty')           # => false
```

This setup is working for me.