# How to prevent Ember Data from saving attribute (ie., Read-only attribute)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jsonapi-resources

I am creating an online form builder using Ember 2.0 on the front-end and Rails 4.2 on the back-end with the json_api_resources gem.

In the process of publishing a form, a user must be able to cut/paste a snippet of code into his/her webpage in order to 'ajax in' the form they have configured.

Thus the 'embed-snippet' attribute of the Form model should be read-only. I do not want the contents of the snippet field to be sent back to the server when the user makes a change to the form and re-saves the record.

Some approaches I have considered:

- Modifying the serializer to check for this specific attribute and drop it from the payload before sending it to the back-end
- Converting the 'embed-snippet' field to a separate model with a relationship to the Form model, and then excluding it somehow from the save
- Creating a new Ember Data attribute type

Ideally there would be a better way to deal with this problem.

Something like:

```
'DS.attr('string', { readOnly: true })
```

So my question is, what is the best way to ensure the content of this field does not get sent back to the server?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the `{ readOnly: true }` functionality (which makes it easier to add new models/attrs) you can customize the `serializeAttribute` method on the `JSONAPISerializer`:

(in `serializers/application.js`):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  serializeAttribute(snapshot, json, key, attribute) {
    // do not serialize the attribute!
    if (attribute.options && attribute.options.readOnly) {
      return;
    }
    this._super(...arguments);
  },
});
```

Comment: I'll have to try that. I've just been deleting keys from the outgoing payload in the serializer. This is a nice solution

Comment: This is an ultra-fantastic solution, as it lets you keep the attribute definitions in the model where they belong. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to do this is to create a custom serializer for the form model and use the `attrs` property to prevent the attribute from being serialized.

In `app/serializers/form.js`:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    attrs: {
        embedSnippet: { serialize: false }
    }
});
```

For more information and examples on attrs see the API documentation http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#property_attrs

Answer (score 3):

You can also control this from the backend, using `json-api-resources`. In whatever the appropriate resource file is, you can control which attributes are allowed to be *retrieved from the backend* and which attributes are allowed to be *accepted by the backend*. Like so:

```
def self.fetchable_fields(context)
  super - [
    :whatever_attribute_not_to_fetch_from_backend
  ]
end

def self.creatable_fields(context)
  super - [
    :embed_snippet,
    :another_attribute_not_accepted_from_post
  ]
end
```

This may not be what you're looking for since it won't prevent the attributes from being *sent* to the backend, but rather prevents them from being *accepted*. But it's another option.

---

#### UPDATE

Depending on your use case, you may also need to use this:

```
def self.updatable_fields(context)
  super - [:whatever]
end
```