# How to prevent Ember Data from saving a read-only attribute for ActiveModelSerializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I am trying to use the `{readOnly: true}` functionality with `ActiveModelSerializer` by customizing the serialize method to ignore readOnly attributes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829966/how-to-prevent-ember-data-from-saving-attribute-ie-read-only-attribute) for `JSONAPISerializer` or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588286/non-persistent-attributes-in-emberjs) for `RESTSerializer`, to prematurely save on upload bandwidth.

Does anyone know if something similar can be done with `ActiveModelSerializer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `ActiveModelSerializer` and `JSONAPISerializer` extends `JSONSerializer`. `serializeAttribute` method is inherited from JSONSerializer. So I don't see any reason you can't adopt the solution given in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588286/non-persistent-attributes-in-emberjs) you already mentioned.

The [other answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589563/3167221) relies on a very old API version of `RESTSerializer` which has been removed before ember-data 1.x release. This has also been mentioned in [another answer to same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427096/3167221).